# TypeScript Cannot read property of undefined - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this email model:

```
export class Email{
    to: Array<
        {
            email: string
            name: string
        }
    >
    from: {
        email: string
        name: string
    }
    cc: Array<
        {
            email: string
            name: string
        }
    >
    bcc: Array<
        {
            email: string
            name: string
        }
    >
    subject: string
    body: string
    type: string
}
```

Then I import the email model and declare it in the class like this:

```
import { Email } from '@/models/email';

export class BuilderJobComponent implements OnInit {
    emailJobData: Email
```

Later on, inside a class method I try to set a value but I get undefined. What am I not understanding about this?

> Cannot read property 'from' of undefined

```
this.emailJobData.from.email = email
this.emailJobData.from.name  = name

// set the To address
if( Recipient ){
    this.emailJobData.to.push({ email: Recipient, name: '' })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared variable `emailJobData`, but did not assign any value to it. Hence, it's value is `undefined`. And undefined doesn't have any properties.

The type after colon only defines the type that can be assigned to the variable, but does not assign any value.

In your code, replace

```
emailJobData: Email;
```

with

```
emailJobData: Email = new Email();
```

And you should be good.

EDIT: To expand on fixing the issue, it's a good idea to have a constructor in your class that will initialize the values / objects in your class to the expected values. Of course, this depends on the business logic - sometimes you would expect undefined values instead of empty array / empty object, etc, so update accordingly - below is just an example.

```
export class AddressWithDisplayValue {
    email: string;
    name: string;
}

export class Email{
    from: AddressWithDisplayValue;
    to: AddressWithDisplayValue[];
    cc: AddressWithDisplayValue[];
    bcc: AddressWithDisplayValue[];
    subject: string;
    body: string;
    type: string;
    
    constructor() {
        this.from = new AddressWithDisplayValue();
        this.to = [];
        this.cc = [];
        this.bcc = [];
    }
}
```

Then, after it was initialized with `emailJobData = new Email()` you will be able to set those properties, e.g.

```
this.emailJobData.from.email = email;
```

Comment: You are correct as that did fix the initial problem, but then I get, Cannot set 'email' of undefined, so from is now undefined. Is there any way around that, without explicitly setting from, like this: ```emailJobData.from = { name: '', email: '' }``` before i set the values?

Comment: I've edited the answer to cover that. You'll probably want to read up on how both JavaScript and TypeScript (which is compiled to JavaScript) work - there are some gotchas which might seem counter intuitive :)

Comment: Ahh, I see exactly what you mean now. I appreciate the answer :)